# Not able to read Command line argument in shell script using getopt in OS X Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, script

I am trying to write a program (using shell script or bash script) which accept command line argument using getopt.

It is working fine on Linux terminal but when I am using it on OS X Terminal it is not able to read the provided command line argument.

a sample code :

```
OPTS=`getopt -o f:l: --long FirstName:,LastName: -n 'parse-options' --   "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi
echo "$OPTS"
eval set -- "$OPTS"
NEWLINE=$'\n'
while true; do
case "$1" in
  -f | --FirstName ) FirstName="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
  -l | --LastName ) LastName="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
  -- ) shift; break ;;
  * ) break ;;
esac
done
echo "${NEWLINE}"
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "FirstName=$FirstName"
echo "LastName=$LastName"
echo "${NEWLINE}"
sleep 1
```

Input :

```
sh try.sh --FirstName foor --LastName bar
```

Output on Linux (FC19):

```
--------------------------------------------
FirstName=foor

LastName=bar
```

Output on Mac :

```
--------------------------------------------
FirstName=

LastName=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `man getopt`. Basically the `getopt` which is part of macOS doesn't support long option names. Using

```
OPTS=`getopt f:l: $*`
```

works as expected.

PS: The man page also recommends to use `$*` instead of `"$@"` but this is not related to your problem.